# Issue connecting a client to localhost using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, localhost

I'm trying to setup a protected client and protected server connection using sockets. Whenever I run the program I receive a connection error saying the connection was refused. I'm using Java in Eclipse IDE running on MAC OS.  Any ideas why this code cannot connect to my localhost?

Protected Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 7999;
        String user = "George";         
        String password = "abc123";     
        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

        ProtectedClient client = new ProtectedClient();
        client.sendAuthentication(user, password, s.getOutputStream());

        s.close();
    }
```

Protected Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    int port = 7999;    //7999
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket client = s.accept();

    ProtectedServer server = new ProtectedServer();

    if (server.authenticate(client.getInputStream()))
      System.out.println("Client logged in.");
    else
      System.out.println("Client failed to log in.");

    s.close();
}
```

When I run the program I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:373)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:216)
    at ProtectedClient.main(ProtectedClient.java:36)
```

Comment: Have you started your server? Also, it looks like your server will close after one client.

Comment: Did u check the proxy?

Comment: @constantlearner there's no usage of proxy in connecting to loopback interface such as localhost

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the port 7999?

Comment: It would be good practice to remove the `throws Exception` from the main method and handle the Exceptions where they occur

Comment: I'm running both programs at the same time in Eclipse.  How would I start the server first.  I'm able to open localhost in my web browser and everything seems fine.  I've checked my proxies and nothing is checked.  Is there something else I should check with the proxy?  I tried turning off my firewall but I still received the error.  Should I be connecting to local host via MAMP and the localhost settings MAMP gives me?

Comment: _How would I start the server first._ 
In the server project hit run and make sure it is running. Then go into the client project and run that while the server is running.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @JamoBox thanks.  I was screwing up the order I ran the programs.  I was running them at the same time instead of starting the server first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten this error before when using particular sockets. Try a different socket like 5687. (Or if you need that particular socket, try making sure your firewall allows it).

Make sure you call client.close() on the server as well. <strike>If your program worked once it might be blocking that port.</strike>

Comment: If that was the case a BindException would be thrown rather than a generic Exception. However, this is still good practice.

Comment: Thank you for the client.close() suggestion.  I am now receiving "Client logged in." print line.